# Error with file R/W?

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to make a program that writes to a file, and reads it, then finds the average:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        writeToFile("C:\\scores.txt");
    }
    public static void writeToFile (String filename) throws IOException {
      BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;
    int q=0;
      while(i >=0&&q<=20) {
         System.out.print("Enter Grade:");
          i=sc.nextInt();
          outputWriter.write(i);
          outputWriter.newLine();
         q++;
      }
      outputWriter.flush();
      outputWriter.close();
      processFile(filename);
    }
    public static void processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

        try (BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)))) {
            String line;
            int lines=0;
             int intValue= 0;
             int sum = 0;
            while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null){
                intValue = Integer.parseInt(line);
              String sumStr;

              while((sumStr = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
              sum = Integer.parseInt(sumStr);
              intValue = sum + intValue;
           lines++;
              }
          intValue=sum+intValue;

            }    
System.out.println(intValue/lines);
inputReader.close();
        }
}
}
```

Issue is, when I run this, it gets to the 21st grade(Supposed to end at 20) and gives me this error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scorereaderwriter.ScoreReaderWriter.processFile(ScoreReaderWriter.java:48)
    at scorereaderwriter.ScoreReaderWriter.writeToFile(ScoreReaderWriter.java:34)
    at scorereaderwriter.ScoreReaderWriter.main(ScoreReaderWriter.java:18)
    Java Result: 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program fails as soon as it attempts to run `parseInt`, because your `inputReader.readLine()` is returning nothing. What you could do is use `inputReader.read()` to get the integer value.

So for example:

```
int sum = 0;
while((sum = inputReader.read()) != -1) {
    intValue = sum + intValue
}
```

This should save you from having to read the file, convert the integer to string, then convert back to an integer again.

Edit: Also, check your first while loop, it runs 21 times instead of 20.